# PhoneGap - Select specific hardware device in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a PhoneGap app on a Mac. I can spin up the iOS simulator by building, then running the following command:

> phonegap run ios

The issue i'm having is that running this command always spins up iOS 7.0.3 (11B507) on a simulated iPhone Retina (3.5-inch). I'd like to be able to test different devices (iPad/previous versions of iOS) but see no way of specifying the device via the run command and haven't added any code to specify device or version.

Is there any way to specify which hardware device to use when debuggion such apps via  the iOS simulator?

Thank you

Comment: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/running-the-ipad-simulator-with-the-phonegap-command-line-tools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cordova command instead of phonegap to run a specific device. First install cordova globally

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Then you can check the available devices for the IOS Simulator with the command

```
ios-sim showdevicetypes
```

This will give you a list such as the following:

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone, 8.0
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad, 8.0
```

Finally, to select one device to run on the Simulator use the following command replacing the string for the device's name of your choice:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="device-name"
```

Examples:

```
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-5s"
cordova emulate ios --target="iPad-Retina"
```